# We are implementing global keyboard and mouse listeners, will they be detected by antiviruses as key-loggers?

Tags: keylistener, mouselistener, antivirus, mouse-listeners

For our commercial Windows and MacOS application, we have implemented a global keyboard, mouse listener, using Python script. We bundle it as exe and package it into our app.

Will this be flagged by Anti-virus?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your code will be flagged by uploading it to Virus Total. Due to heuristics it is likely that any code which monitors all keyboard and mouse input will be flagged by at least one AV app.

You can also create a number of VMs to test popular AV software in. You will need one VM per AV app you want to test because they generally do not cooperate well. This allows you to test the real-time protection systems which VirusTotal generally doesn't (it's just a file scan, which may involve some execution but is mostly "passive").

Comment: VirusTotal only checks against the binary (some might implement simple heuristic to detect default behavior). When actually run in normal use, AV also can detect different action by the program, which may trigger detection. OP's best bet will be setting up VMs and test against popular AVs.

Comment: @Martheen it's a Python script, AV software can read it. VMs is a good idea though.

Comment: The ability to read it doesn't mean the AV will bother to fully scan all possible path. I've had AHK scripts that run well until it attempts to clean up VS folder output